# How we can display informations in a top bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to display some informations about the user in a bar at the top of the application (in appbar ?). You have perhaps seen already some applications which displays some important informations in the top bar of the application like the revenue the users has won or the points he have accumulated for example.
Do you know how we can do it in flutter ?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is the type of information? What do you want to show there? You can set anything as the `title` of the `AppBar`

Comment: i want to show the revenue of the user because my application give money to users

Answer (score 0):

First thing, In Flutter everything that appears on the screen is a `Widget`.

So normally you would do something like this for `AppBar`:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But if you inspect the `AppBar`'s code, You'll see that the `title` is defined as a `Widget`. So as long as you provide a `Widget` in the `title`, it will show it.

If you want to show more than just one text in the title, You can use `Column`s or `Row`s which are `Widget`s themselves.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int balance = 1000;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Title'),
            Text('Balance: \$$balance', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            balance += 100;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```